# C#.Net get website folder from web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a website and web api which made on .net platform.

Web api has a `ImageUpload(...)` method. I get images as base64 encoded string and saving after turning into byte[].

Here is the story:

Web api's root folder located at: `domain.com/API` and website's: `domain.com/httpdocs`.

I hold uploaded images in `httpdocs/files/images` folder. So it's different folder than web api's. Therefore I am not able to save images in `httpdocs/files/images` folder. Because web api's context's top folder is `httpdocs/API`. I can't access `httpdocs/` folder.

Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Server.MapPath` to get the server side path.

Comment: Server.MapPath(path) does not allow to get another folder's path than root's. It throws "Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory." error.